# Where can you get the latest twitter4j build for Twitter API 1.1

Tags: twitter4j

I suppose twitter has some restrictions in its new API - which I want to incorporate. The twitter4j site doesn't seem to mention anything on the new API.

Answer (score 0):

use twitter4j jar version 3.0.3 for new twitter api.